# Dice Probability Removal

Tags: probability

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this problem. I have 216 6-sided dice. I roll all of them and remove all the 6s rolled. I repeat, and again remove all the 6s rolled. I do this until I have 125 dice. How many times have I rolled? (I honestly don't know how you would quantify, I would think it could be anywhere between 1 and 91.)

Comment: The correct answer is "it's unable to determine as dice rolling generates random variables". So I need to specify the question: perhaps you need to find the **expected value** of rolls?

Comment: I assumed as such, but all that was written was "how many times have the dice been rolled?" How would you go about figuring out the expected roll value?

Answer (score 0):

If you calculate the expected number, I'd say:

Each roll leaves $5/6$ left, so calculate $(5/6)^n \times 216 = 125$

$n = 3$

Comment: Suppose that you start with $6$ dice and that you are allowed to stop if $5$ (or less) dice are left. Then your answer would be: $n=1$. However, it is for sure that at least $1$ roll is necessary and the possibility that more than $1$ roll is necessary has positive probability. That leads to an expectation that exceeds $1$.

Comment: Of course you are right that I made some assumptions and used formulas based on the actual numbers from this problem. E.g. normal distribution iso binomial stuff.